# The field $C$ is an algebraic closure for $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $E/F$ be an algebraic extension and $C$ be an algebraic closure of $E$.
I want to show that the field $C$ is an algebraic closure also for $F$.

I have done the following:

$C$ is an algebraic closure of $E$, i.e., each polynomial of $E[x]$ has all the roots in $C$. Let $f\in F[x]$ be a non-zero polynomial. 
Since $E$ is an extension of $F$, we have that $f\in E[x]$. 
So, each polymnomial of $F[x]$ has all the roots in $C$.

To conclude that $C$ is an algebraic closure also for $F$, it is left to show that $C/F$ is algebraic, or not?

So, we have to show that each element of $C$ is algebraic over $F$, i.e., for each element $c\in C$ there is a non-zero polynomial $g(x)\in F[x]$, such that $g(c)=0$.

To show that we have to use the fact that $C/E$ is algebraic, or not? But how exactly?

Comment: What's your definition of an algebraic closure of a field $E$?

Comment: @D_S: Are there several of them?

Comment: No, but it isn't immediate that all of them are equivalent, so I wanted to use Mary Star's definition.

Comment: In my notes there is following proposition: $$$$ Let $K/F$ be an extension. We consider the intermediate subset $A=\{a\in K : a\text{ algebraic } |F\}$. $A$ is a field and the extension $A/F$ is algebraic. $A$ is called algebraic closure of $F$ in $K$. @D_S

Comment: There is a difference between an algebraic closure of $F$ and the algebraic closure of $F$ in a given field which contains $F$ (relative algebraic closure).  A relative algebraic closure need not be algebraically closed, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A field extension $C$ of $F$ is an algebraic closure if

1. $C$ is algebraically closed;
2. $C$ is algebraic over $F$.

Property 1 is clearly satisfied.

Now, let's prove that if $K$ is algebraic over $L$ and $M$ is algebraic over $K$, then $M$ is algebraic over $L$. This will show property 2.

Let $c\in M$. Then $c$ satisfies a nonzero polynomial $f(x)\in K[x]$. If $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n$, then $c$ is algebraic over $L'=L(a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n)$, which is finite dimensional over $L$ (see “key fact” below).

By the “key fact”, $L'(c)$ is finite dimensional over $L'$. Thus
$$
[L'(c):L]=[L'(c):L'][L':L]
$$
so $c$ belongs to a finite dimensional extension of $L$ and therefore it is algebraic over $L$.

> ***Key fact*** If $E$ is an extension field of $F$ and $c\in E$, then
>
> 1. $c$ is algebraic over $F$ if and only if $F(c)$ is finite dimensional over $F$;
> 2. if $E$ is finite dimensional over $F$, then $E$ is algebraic over $F$.

Comment: I see... Thanks a lot!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $F \subseteq E \subseteq L$ are fields.  If $L$ is algebraic over $E$, and $E$ is algebraic over $F$, then $L$ is algebraic over $F$.  This result should give you what you want.

Here is a sketch of the proof.  In general, if $A \subseteq B$ are fields, and $b \in B$ is algebraic over $A$, then $A(b)$ (by definition, the intersection of all subfields of $B$ which contain $A$ and the element $b$) is a finite extension of $A$, i.e. it is finite dimensional as a vector space over $A$.  It follows that if $b_1, ... , b_n \in B$ are algebraic over $A$, then $A(b_1, ... , b_n)$ is a finite extension of $A$.  This follows because $A(b_1, ... , b_i) = A(b_1, ... , b_{i-1})(b_i)$ is a finite extension of $A(b_1, ... , b_{i-1})$.

If $x \in L$, then $x$ is the root of a polynomial $f(X) = a_0 + a_1X + \cdots + a_nX^n \in E[X]$.  Now all the $a_i$ are algebraic over $F$, so $F(a_0, ... , a_n)$ is a finite extension of $F$.  Clearly, $x$ is algebraic over $F(a_0, ... , a_n)$, so $F(a_0, ... , a_n)(x) = F(a_0,..., a_n,x)$ is a finite extension of $F(a_0, ... , a_n)$, hence of $F$.

In particular, $x$ is a member of a field which is a finite extension of $F$.  Now, you just need to show that finite extensions are algebraic.

Comment: I see... Thank you very mich!! :-)